# Change IP in Packet request Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html-parsing, spoofing

I am creating a web application that parses through different websites, for example if you search for "stackoverflow" on the app we will search multiple websites, google, yahoo, bing, stackoverflow etc. To get around the fact that I needed to use an api for each and every website I decided to parse through HTML, and so far it works fine. However I do know that if sites like google get couple of unusally fast request from the same IP Address that they will just block that IP, so what I wanted to do is use the users IP and send it in the packet to apps like google will think that the user initiated the request. I have thought of a couple of ways, ex: Have javascript initiate the request, and send back the html, but it just seems like such a drag seeing that I have already written the parser in ruby and I really dont feel that 2 seperate calls would be that efficient. So if anyone has any idea on how to accomplish this either by ip spoofing or another hack I would be eternally grateful. Thanks

Comment: Please take the time to format your question, and use correct grammar, punctuation, capitalization and spelling. Stack Overflow likes questions that are concise, well written, and encyclopedia like.

Answer (score 0):

You could use banks of proxy servers, but that is costly.

Personally, I'd go with the APIs, knowing I was doing things the approved ways, and not worry about trying to circumvent their session-sniffing algorithms.

You're taking a "short-cut" that is probably going to be slower than using their APIs, especially when you consider time spent rewriting your code. It's a continuing battle trying to deal with HTML scraping, because they will all be changing their HTML layout, breaking your scrapers. Their APIs will change much more slowly and less often, if at all, so your code would hum along.